# Converting read char to int c++

Tags: c++, terminal

In my program, the name of the file with the values (at most 2-digit numbers) to be read is given in the terminal and my main() is as below:

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   //assume argv[1] is a filename to open
   ifstream the_file ( argv[1] )
   if ( !the_file.is_open() ){
      cout<<"Could not open file" << endl;
      return 0;
   }

   char x;
   int array[10];
   int x_int;
   while ( the_file.get ( x ) ){
        for (int i=0; i<10;i++){
             array[i] = (int)x;
        }
   }
      
}
```

However, I am getting some odd number.

My mistake is definitely at `array[i] = (int)x;` line, but

how can I convert read char value to int? Or is there any other method to read them as int type?

I want to have the values taken from input file work as integers, not as a single digit

My actual input file (.txt) is:

```
75
95
1
2
45
65
98
6
7
9
```

Comment: What does your file contain? A sequence of digits ('0'-'9'), A sequence of numbers (possibly multi-digit), or binary data? Give an example.

Comment: @interjay, it has at most 2-digit numbers like 55, 78, 2, 4. etc.

Comment: So reading it one char at a time as you do in the question won't help you, and neither will converting a char to an int. Please edit the question to describe the file format and the output you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I convert read char value to int?

You can fix this by just writing

```
array[i] = x - '0';
```

ASCII characters like `'1'` or `'5'` cannot be directly casted to get their numeric equivalents. Make sure you've been reading a digit character when doing so, e.g. using the [`std::isdigit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) function.

---

As for your primary concern after the question edit:

> Or is there any other method to read them as int type?

The usual method to read in `int` types is just apply the `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, int&)` like so

```
int array[10];
int i = 0;
int x_int;
while ( the_file >> x_int && i < 10) {
    array[i] = x_int;
    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve your problem is to use `getline()` and read it into a `char buf[MAX_LINE_LEN]` where `MAX_LINE_LEN` is the maximum size of the input line. Instead of `(int)x` use `atoi(buf)`. You will need to include `stdlib.h`.

You also could just use `>>` operator to read into `array[i]` directly. If you have to read one character at a time, you can use `num = num * 10 + (x - '0')` computation in a loop breaking on delimiters (non-digits), but this is a more complicated solution.

Comment: Why overcomplicate it?